# Convert dictionary entries into variables

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a Pythonic way to assign the values of a dictionary to its keys, in order to convert the dictionary entries into variables?
I tried this out:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> for key,val in d.items():
        exec('exec(key)=val')
            
        exec(key)=val
                 ^ 
        SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am certain that the key-value pairs are correct because they were previously defined as variables by me before. I then stored these variables in a dictionary (as key-value pairs) and would like to reuse them in a different function. I could just define them all over again in the new function, but because I may have a dictionary with about 20 entries, I thought there may be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: It is not a good idea to create variables dynamically.

Comment: @Zero Piraeus - My question relates to entries created by me and not by a different user, so it's slighlty different from the question posted in the post you mentioned

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary why not?

Comment: See also [Elegant way to unpack limited dict values into local variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755178/elegant-way-to-unpack-limited-dict-values-into-local-variables-in-python)

Comment: @ggorlen I deduced that they are essentially the same question, and that the other version, although much less popular, is higher quality.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This was what I was looking for:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> for key,val in d.items():
        exec(key + '=val')
```

Comment: `list(map(exec, ("{0}={1}".format(x[0],x[1]) for x in d.items())))`

Comment: @dbliss    `for k,v in d.items(): exec(k+'=v')`

Comment: Sweet answer, saves me having to declare a boatload of mongodb variables.  @dblis you can just do `for key,val in dp.items(): exec(key + '=val')` That's one line in my book.

Comment: Careful with eval, your dict might have `import shutil;shutil.rmtree('/')` or worse in it.

Comment: Should be downvoted. No need to use exec, see locals answers elsewhere.

Comment: @GringoSuave, which answer you are referring to?..

Comment: @Kirby, top answer currently by Peque.  Fundamental idea should be avoided, namespace or dict best, followed by locals() as least bad options.  Exec() probably the absolute last resort.

Comment: @HappyPy I have a problem with your implementation. If I try to use the variables later on outside the for loop, i.e. `my_new_var=str(c)`, I get `NameError: name 'c' is not defined`. How did you used them so? Thanks

Comment: This solution does not work inside a function, but only if the variables are global

Answer (score 184):

You can do it in a single line with:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> locals().update(d)
>>> a
1
```

However, you should be careful with [how Python may optimize locals/globals access when using this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277519/how-can-i-pass-my-locals-and-access-the-variables-directly-from-another-function).

### Note

I think editing `locals()` like that is generally a bad idea. If you think `globals()` is a better alternative, think it twice! :-D

Instead, I would rather always use a namespace.

With Python 3 you can:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace    
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> n = SimpleNamespace(**d)
>>> n.a
1
```

If you are stuck with Python 2 or if you need to use [some features missing in `types.SimpleNamespace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345836/3577054), you can also:

```
>>> from argparse import Namespace    
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> n = Namespace(**d)
>>> n.a
1
```

If you are not expecting to modify your data, you may as well consider using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), also available in Python 3.

Comment: Note, does not work inside a function.  
(Will "work" with globals() but it will assign global variables, not local to the function...)

Comment: I got the error `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'update'`, why?

Comment: @CharlieParker Maybe you forgot the parenthesis? 

Comment: @Peque I didn't. My command is `locals.update(mat_dict)` in my script. Weird hu?

Comment: oh I see `locals()` duh! Thanks! :)

Comment: You can also use `globals().update(d)`. This would work inside a function.

Comment: [The docs explicitly warn not to update the return value of `locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).

Answer (score 34):

You already have a perfectly good dictionary. Just use that. If you know what the keys are going to be, and you're absolutely sure this is a reasonable idea, you can do something like

```
a, b = d['a'], d['b']
```

but most of the time, you should just use the dictionary. (If using the dictionary is awkward, you are probably not organizing your data well; ask for help reorganizing it.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm sure what the keys will be because I created them, and just want to use exactly the same variable names elsewhere. I was just wondering whether there's a more automatic way to do it, as I may have over 20 entries.

Comment: @user2635863: You might be looking for a [class](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). If you have 20 variables that all need saving, you have a problem.

Comment: @HappyPy you shouldn't need 20+ named variables, the logic should allow you to unpack the dictionary directly in the other function (for example, your 20+ variables could be named arguments of a function)

Answer (score 22):

you can use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> a, b = itemgetter('a', 'b')(d)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

Comment: This is the Pythonic way to do destructure dicts. Though not as shorthand as Javascript it's very easy to understand for the reader what's going on and does not mix data and variable names.

Comment: Good one, but unfortunately `foobar, foobaz = itemgetter("foobar", "foobaz")(dictionary)` is not so attractive. Everything looks pretty good with single-letter variable names. Plus there's an import per script for something you might want to do only once or twice.

Comment: How would this be easier than unpacking 20+ named variables as is the case with OP's problem? You can do `itemgetter(*d.keys())(d)` but you'd have to type each one named variable on the left side anyway

Answer (score 13):

Consider the "Bunch" solution in [Python: load variables in a dict into namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597278/python-load-variables-in-a-dict-into-namespace). Your variables end up as part of a new object, not locals, but you can treat them as variables instead of dict entries.

```
class Bunch(object):
    def __init__(self, adict):
        self.__dict__.update(adict)

d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
vars = Bunch(d)
print vars.a, vars.b
```

Comment: Why are you shadowing [vars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)?

Comment: SimpleNamespace has been included for quite a while, though name is cumbersome I'd agree.

Answer (score 6):

Python has great support for list unpacking, but not dict or object unpacking. The most unsurprising and Pythonic approach seems to be accessing each item by hand to build an intermediate tuple as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18090853/6243352):

```py
a, b = d['a'], d['b']
```

However, if you have a lot of properties, or variable names are long, it can get nasty to do:

```py
great, wow, awesome = dictionary['great'], dictionary['wow'], dictionary['awesome']
```

For context, the JavaScript equivalent of the above (destructuring) is:

```js
const {great, wow, awesome} = dictionary;
```

Here's an option that is a bit more dynamic:

```py
>>> dictionary = dict(great=0, wow=1, awesome=2)
>>> great, wow, awesome = (dictionary[k] for k in ("great", "wow", "awesome"))
>>> great
0
>>> awesome
2
```

This is still verbose; you could write a function to abstract things a bit, but unfortunately you still have to type everything twice:

```py
>>> def unpack(dct, *keys):
...     return (dct[k] for k in keys)
... 
>>> dictionary = dict(great=0, wow=1, awesome=2)
>>> great, wow, awesome = unpack(dictionary, "great", "wow", "awesome")
```

You can generalize this to work on objects too:

```
>>> def unpack(x, *keys):
...     if isinstance(x, dict):
...         return (x[k] for k in keys)
...     return (getattr(x, k) for k in keys)
...
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Foo = namedtuple("Foo", "a b c d e")
>>> foo = Foo(a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4)
>>> c, b, d, a = unpack(foo, "c", "b", "d", "a")
>>> d
3
```

After all is said and done, unpacking by hand on multiple lines is probably best for real production code that you need to be safe and comprehensible:

```py
>>> great = dictionary["great"]
>>> wow = dictionary["wow"]
>>> awesome = dictionary["awesome"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
var=pd.Series({'a':1, 'b':2})
#update both keys and variables
var.a=3
print(var.a,var['a'])
```

Comment: i love pandas, but this might be overkill (requiring pandas just so you get variables as an accesor).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I have a dict where the values are pandas dataframes. So made total sense to use this solution. Thank you!