# How do I create a Python namespace (argparse.parse_args value)?

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

To interactively test my python script, I would like to create a `Namespace` object, similar to what would be returned by `argparse.parse_args()`.
The obvious way,

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.parse_args()
Namespace()
>>> parser.parse_args("-a")
usage: [-h]
: error: unrecognized arguments: - a

Process Python exited abnormally with code 2
```

may result in Python repl exiting (as above) on a silly error.

So, **what is the easiest way to create a Python namespace with a given set of attributes?**

E.g., I can create a `dict` on the fly (`dict([("a",1),("b","c")])`) but I cannot use it as a `Namespace`:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'
```

PS. The new [`exit_on_error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error) option looks like a promising alternative to creating a `Namespace` object, but it is [severely broken](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85427), apparently by design.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You can create a simple class:

```
class Namespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

and it'll work the exact same way as the `argparse` `Namespace` class when it comes to attributes:

```
>>> args = Namespace(a=1, b='c')
>>> args.a
1
>>> args.b
'c'
```

Alternatively, just *import the class*; it is available from the `argparse` module:

```
from argparse import Namespace

args = Namespace(a=1, b='c')
```

As of Python 3.3, there is also [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace), which essentially does the same thing:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> args = SimpleNamespace(a=1, b='c')
>>> args.a
1
>>> args.b
'c'
```

The two types are distinct; `SimpleNamespace` is primarily used for the `sys.implementation` attribute and the return value of `time.get_clock_info()`.

Further comparisons:

- Both classes support equality testing; for two instances of the same class, `instance_a == instance_b` is true if they have the same attributes with the same values.
- Both classes have a helpful `__repr__` to show what attributes they have.
- `Namespace()` objects support containment testing; `'attrname' in instance` is true if the namespace instance has an attribute namend `attrname`. `SimpleNamespace` does not.
- `Namespace()` objects have an undocumented `._get_kwargs()` method that returns a sorted list of `(name, value)` attributes for that instance. You can get the same for either class using `sorted(vars(instance).items())`.
- While `SimpleNamespace()` is implemented in C and `Namespace()` is implemented in Python, attribute access is no faster because both use the same `__dict__` storage for the attributes. Equality testing and producing the representation are a little faster for `SimpleNamespace()` instances.

Comment: The former simple class is actually types.SimpleNamespace: see https://docs.python.org/dev/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace.

Comment: @Ofer: no, `SimpleNamespace` is not actually used by `argparse`; `argparse.Namespace` is a pure-Python class unique to that library, `types.SimpleNamespace` is the class originally developed for `sys.implementation` and later used for `time.get_clock_info()` as well. It's implemented in C.

Comment: To implement `'attrname' in instance` as `argparse.Namespace` does, the `__contains__` method can be added to the class definition above: `def __contains__(self, item): return item in self.__dict__`

Answer (score 32):

It is now recommended to use SimpleNamespace from the types module. It does the same thing as the accepted answer except for it will be faster and have a few more builtins such as equals and repr.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

sn = SimpleNamespace()
sn.a = 'test'
sn.a

# output
'test'
```

Comment: `argparse.Namespace` also implements `__repr__` and `__eq__`. `SimpleNamespace` *is* implemented in C, but only the equality testing and `repr()` output will be a bit faster because of that. Attribute access is just as fast because both use the exact same mechanism to store and look up attributes. `argparse.Namespace()` also implements `__contains__`, so you can use `if something in ns_instance`, and there is an undocumented `._get_kwargs()` method; `SimpleNamespace()` doesn't have either.

Answer (score 6):

First create a dict and then use the dict to create an namespace:

```py
from argparse import Namespace
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
ns = Namespace(**x)
print(ns.a) #output 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer short code, you only need to add one extra line to define an empty class:

```
class dummy:pass
obj = dummy()
```

where `dummy` can be any string not defined in your program. Then `obj` will be a Namespace.

You can also initialize some namespace members in one line:

```
class dummy:a=1;b=2
obj = dummy()

print(obj.a+' '+obj.b)
```

It is a design deficiency of Python that there is no straight-forward way of creating the most basic Python object (i.e., Namespace object) just like creating tuple, list, dict, etc. If I am the designer, I will let `a=<>` to create an empty Namespace `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as @sds said, this feature is currently broken in cpython

An alternative solution for your problem without creating a namespace instance could be the `exit_on_error` parameter of the ArgumentParser constructor.

If set to false, it should not exit your REPL.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects

Comment: Nope, this parameter is [severely broken](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85427).

Answer (score -5):

[argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) show various examples of what you're trying to do:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a")
parser.parse_args(['-a 12'])
>>> Namespace(a=' 12')
```

Comment: no good, as I explain in the question: a small error and the repl is _dead_

Comment: This doesn't let you interactively test your code that is using the `Namespace` instance.

Comment: @sds I may be missing something on the 'repl is dead' part of your question but isn't it because the `ArgumentParser` you're using is missing the `add_argument` call ? I do understand that you don't want to recreate the same `ArgumentParser` in your test but it could be created in a separate method called in the test to be retrieved. @MartijnPieters can't you just do create the `ArgumentParser` this way and then pass it in you method that's using it ? `my_method_using_arg_parse(fake_namespace)