# How can I create multiple Pandas dataframes from a list of pickle files?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a Pandas dataframe for each of a list of pickle files.

If I use this code:

```
dfs = [pd.read_pickle(file) for file in DATA_PROCESSED.iterdir()]
```

I will get a list, but I want also to make a correspondence between filename and dataframe name. In this case I will get only dfs[0] e.g.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension instead of a list comprehension. You can strip the extension name from the dictionary key for easier access later using `.strip('.pkl')`, replacing `.pkl` with whatever extension you are using.

```
dfs = {file.strip('.pkl'):pd.read_pickle(file) for file in DATA_PROCESSED.iterdir()}
```

Then you can access each using normal dictionary syntax:

```
dfs['filename']
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have individual dataframe, without belonging to a list or dict?

Comment: Not safely, as far as I know, short of following the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090672/convert-dictionary-entries-into-variables-python/36059129#36059129) (which I *do not* recommend)