# Get values from Django's form in efective way

Tags: python, django, string

I'm getting `values` from `form` in `django` like this:

```py
            tantou1 = request.POST.get("1tantou", "")
            tantou2 = request.POST.get("2tantou", "")
            tantou3 = request.POST.get("3tantou", "")
            tantou4 = request.POST.get("4tantou", "")

            hidzuke1 = request.POST.get("1hidzuke", "")
            hidzuke2 = request.POST.get("2hidzuke", "")
            hidzuke3 = request.POST.get("3hidzuke", "")
            hidzuke4 = request.POST.get("4hidzuke", "")
```

which works, but I have a lot of values to get and this way took too much space in my code. I would like to ask, if there is not a way to define this variables in (for example) loop? Something like:

```py
data_vars = [tantou1="", tantou2="", tantou3="", tantou4="", hidzuke1="", hidzuke2="", hidzuke3="", hidzuke4=""]

for var in data_vars:
    var = request.POST.get(str(var.__name__), "")
```

or so?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that `HttpRequest.POST` is a [dictionary-like object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/393652) you can unpack a dict to variables a number of ways, but they recommend namespacing. I've just tried this and it works:

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace 

n = SimpleNamespace(**request.POST.dict())
```

You can then access your variables as:

```py
n.tantou1
n.tantou2
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just pass `request.POST` into your form's `__init__`, like so:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        ...
```