# Python 3 - parsing .json

Tags: python, json

a json file = a.json

```
{"xt_Adminserver_URL": "10.0.1.5:2346"}.
{"LinuxAdServer": "10.0.1.6"}.
{"WindowsAdminServer": "10.0.1.8"}.
{"JlLmsServer": "12.17.10.81:1688 "}.
{"token": "KT99999"}.
{"WONumber": "WO0000123456"}.
{"VMbuilderID": "A12G456"}.
{"QAreviewerID": "B65I321"}.
{"utilization": "n"}.
{"static_fqdn": "False"}.
{"branch": "new_dev"}
```

I'm trying to bring each one in as a variable in a python script, what is the correct way to read this and assign variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert dictionary entries into variables - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090672/convert-dictionary-entries-into-variables-python)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you would need to import json module and then use it's load method to load the specified file.

```
import json 

f = open ('dataFile.json', "r") 
data = json.loads(f.read())
```

Then you can this data object like normal dictionaries in python.

If you just want to deserialize a json string to dictionary.
You can pass the string to `json.loads(jsonString)` and it would convert it to a dictionary.
Hope this helps.