# Convert dictionary entries into variables in function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, nameerror

I want to get variables for work in function from dict.

Simple example

```
>>> def func(atrs):
...     for k,v in atrs.items():
...             exec(k + '=v')
...     
...     # do smth here with vars
...     
...     print(locals())   # lets see that 'a' exists
...     print(a)          # lets use 'a'
```

And after I use this func I get the error.

```
>>> func({'a':1, 'b':5})
{'atrs': {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, 'k': 'b', 'v': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 5}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in func
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

But we can see that 'a' exists in defined variables.
What I doing wrong?

I see this and it works if we dont use functions.
[Convert dictionary entries into variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090672/convert-dictionary-entries-into-variables)

But I need use functions.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discouraged you to use this kind of method but you can use `locals()` (or `vars()`) to create variables dynamically:

```
def func(attrs):
    for k, v in attrs.items():
        locals()[k] = v
    print(locals())
    print(a)
    print(b)

func({'a':1, 'b':5})
```

Output:

```
{'attrs': {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, 'k': 'b', 'v': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 5}
1
5
```

If you want this variables exist out of the scope of `func` function, replace `locals()` or `vars()` by `globals()`.

Comment: No, I just get the same error: NameError: name 'a' is not defined
Can it be problem with my python interpreter or smth like this?

Comment: Do you copy/paste my code?

Comment: Yes, I copy paste your code.
https://imgur.com/3PZwMAG

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your code works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I dont understand why, but it works if we define this vars like globals, not locals.

```
def func(attrs):
    for k, v in attrs.items():
        globals()[k] = v
    
    # or we can use this instead of 'for' loop
    # globals().update(attrs)
    
    print(locals())
    print(globals())
    print(a)
    print(b)

func({'a':1, 'b':5})
```

Output

```
{'attrs': {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, 'k': 'b', 'v': 5}
{'__name__': '__main__', ..., 'a': 1, 'b': 5}
1
5
```